# What's the conf file reading between login and non-login shell?

Tags: shell, configuration

I found that those are `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.bash_login`, `.profile`.

What's the reading sequence between them?

Comment: See the `INVOCATION` section of the bash manual.  Meanwhile I am sure this is a duplicate of something.

Comment: Try to do some research before asking, [man bash](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=bash&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian+6.0+squeeze&format=html&locale=en) contains all the information

Comment: From man bash, non-interactively means non-login shells? Thank you~

Comment: `An interactive  shell  is one started without non-option arguments and without the -c option whose standard input and error are both connected to  terminals  (as determined by isatty(3)), or one started with the -i option.` - from man bash. This means if any of these requirements are not fulfilled it is a non-interactive shell, e.g. if you run a script with the `#!/bin/bash` shebang it is a non interactive shell.

Comment: Interactive and login are orthogonal concepts.  You'll be less confused if you stop trying to align them.  All 4 combinations can exist, from interactive login shells to non-interactive non-login shells.

Comment: @jw013 Can you clarify?  I'm pretty sure login shell (or interactive with `--login`) means it takes a separate codepath from an interactive shell.

Comment: @jw013 Nearest thing to a duplicate I can find is [Difference between .bashrc and .bash_profile](http://superuser.com/questions/183870/difference-between-bashrc-and-bash-profile/183980) on superuser.com.

Comment: @Mikel That's what I said right?  sam was asking if non-interactive == non-login, or if some other sort of relation between the two traits existed.  My previous comment said that there is none, since all 4 possibilities can exist.  You can have non-interactive, non-login shells, interactive non-login shells, login non-interactive shells, or interactive login shells.

Comment: @jw013 http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40708/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-bashrc-bash-profile-gnomer but neither fully addresses this question

Answer (score 8):

Basically, if it's a login shell it sources `/etc/profile` then `.bash_profile`.  If it's not a login shell, but you're at a terminal, it sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` then `.bashrc`.

But it's actually a lot more complicated.

The way I read the man page:

```
if bash_mode; then
    if login_shell; then
        if test -e /etc/profile; then source /etc/profile; fi
        if test -e .bash_profile; then source .bash_profile
        elif test -e .bash_login; then source .bash_login
        elif test -e .profile; then source .profile; fi
    elif interactive_shell || remote_shell; then
        if test -e /etc/bash.bashrc; then source /etc/bash.bashrc
        if test -e .bashrc; then source .bashrc; fi
    elif test -n "$BASH_ENV"; then
        source "$BASH_ENV"
    fi
elif sh_mode; then
    if login_shell; then
        if test -e /etc/profile; then source /etc/profile; fi
        if test -e .profile; then source .profile; fi
    elif interactive_shell; then
         if test -n "$ENV"; then
             source "$ENV"
         fi
    fi
fi
```

It's a login shell any time the shell is run as `-bash` (note the minus sign) or with the `-l` option.  This usually happens when you log in using the `login` command (Linux virtual consoles do this), over ssh, or if your terminal emulator has the "login shell" option enabled.

It's an interactive shell any time standard input is a terminal, or bash was started with the `-i` option.  Note that if the shell is also a login shell, bash doesn't check if the shell is interactive.  For this reason, `.bash_profile` usually contains code to source `.bashrc`, so you can share the same settings between interactive and login shells.