# Why is Cygwin not sourcing my .bashrc?

Tags: bash, cygwin

I'm switching to Cygwin from the bash shell that ships with Git for Windows, and for some strange reason the .bashrc file is not being sourced when I open a new Terminal.  I have to

```
source .bashrc
```

manually just to get my normal settings.  `echo $0 $-` returns `-bash himBH`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Need this output: `echo $0 $-`

Answer (score 8):

The minus at the start of `$0` means that `bash` is being started as a login shell.

In this case, `bash` reads initialization commands from `.bash_profile`, not `.bashrc`.

The simplest fix is to create `~/.bash_profile` if it doesn't already exist, and put

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

at the top.

See also: [What's the conf file reading between login and non-login shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43953/whats-the-conf-file-reading-between-login-and-non-login-shell)