# What is the difference between ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile?

Tags: bash, profile

What is the difference between `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the conf file reading between login and non-login shell?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43953/whats-the-conf-file-reading-between-login-and-non-login-shell)

Comment: And for the other part of your question, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3052/alternative-to-bashrc

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The `.profile` was the original profile configuration for the Bourne shell (a.k.a., `sh`). `bash`, being a Bourne compatible shell will read and use it. The `.bash_profile` on the other hand is only read by `bash`. It is intended for commands that are incompatible with the standard Bourne shell.

Comment: If i am wrong, do correct me.. .profile is used by any Bourne compatible shell whereas .bash_profile is used by bash only.. am i right?

Comment: @lakesh: Yes, any shell providing bourne compatibility will read `.profile`. E.g., `bash` and `ksh` but not `csh` or `tcsh`. And `zsh` provides both `sh` and `csh` compatibility so it will read both `.profile` and `.login`, as well as `zsh` specific dot files.

Comment: is there any tutorial to read up on this bash and ksh stuff? never heard of these before...

Comment: You could start with the [UNIX Shell History](http://www.softpanorama.org/People/Shell_giants/introduction.shtml).

Comment: @bahamat in my testing, and according to [this gnu doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html), `~/.profile` is only read by `sh` if `/etc/profile` does not exist (note my `sh` is invoking `bash`).

Answer (score 58):

The original `sh` sourced `.profile` on startup.

`bash` will try to source `.bash_profile` first, but if that doesn't exist, it will source `.profile`<sup>1</sup>.

Note that if `bash` is started as `sh` (e.g. `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/bash`) or is started with the `--posix` flag, it tries to emulate `sh`, and only reads `.profile`.

Footnotes:

1. Actually, the first one of `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, `.profile`

See also:

- [Bash Reference Manual - Startup Files](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files)
- [UNIX sh man page - Invocation](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sh&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Unix+Seventh+Edition&arch=default&format=html)

Comment: A small point about `bash` started as `sh`: `~/.profile` will only be read if `/etc/profile` does not exist. This [gnu doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) explains it all in agonizing detail.

Comment: so if `.bash_profile` exists, `.profile` is not read?

Comment: @a06e Correct (unless `.bash_profile` does something like `source .profile`).

Answer (score 23):

You know many shells exist in the UNIX world, but most of them are:

- **Bourne shell**: `/bin/sh` (Inventor: Stephen Bourne)
- **BASH** (Bourne Again Shell): `/bin/bash` (Inventor: Brian Fox, under GNU project) (powerful shell)
- **C shell**: `/bin/csh` (Inventor: Bill Joy, Inventor of TCP/IP Stack)
- **Korn shell**: `/bin/ksh` (Inventor: David Korn under Bell Labs)
- **Z shell**: `/bin/zsh` (Powerful shell)
- **TENEX C shell**: `/bin/tcsh` (derived from C Shell)
- **Debian Almquist shell**: `/bin/dash` (Derived from  Almquist shell (ash under NetBSD project)) (Dash born from lenny)

**But your question** is about `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.profile`:

When you you log in to a UNIX machine, it redirects to your home directory, according to the shell chosen by an administrator in the last field of `/etc/passwd` such as :

```
mohsen:x:1000:1000:Mohsen Pahlevanzadeh,,,:/home/mohsen:/bin/bash
```

Your shell runs, and by default each shell has a set file for `login` and `logout`. When you log in on bash, `~/.profile` is run and when you `logout`, `~/.bash_logout` is run.
`~/.bash_history` file keeps your input command.

### Initialization file in each shell

#### TENEX C shell

- `~/.login` When you login
- `~/.logout` When you logout
- `~/.tcshrc` same as `~./bashrc` in bash

You can set variable `$histfile` as name of history file and variable `$history` as number of commands to keeping.

#### Z shell

Indeed it's powerful shell and if you get free time, be sure migrate to it.

Except of other shell, Z shell has many configuration file and initialization files, just i write:

```
$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv
$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile
$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin
$ZDOTDIR/.zlogout
/tmp/zsh*
/etc/zshenv
/etc/zprofile
/etc/zshrc
/etc/zlogin
```

Note: if `$ZDOTDIR` unset, home set.

#### C shell

Note: TENEX C shell was forked from C shell. C shell supports by BSD.
If you are familiar with C language programing, you should be comfortable since its syntax is similar.

```
~/.login
~/.cshrc
~/.logout
```

Note: csh is old. Use tcsh instead.

#### Korn Shell

- `~/.profile`
- rc file: user defined
- logout file: N/A

#### Bourne Again SHell (BASH)

It's very very powerful shell and born under GNU project and forked by Bourne Shell.

```
~/.bash_login
~/.bash_logout
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.bash_history
```

When you login, bash runs `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_profile` runs `~/.bashrc`. Indeed `~/.bashrc` isn't bash initialization file, because bash doesn't run it.

#### Bourne shell

It dead. Even when you use `man sh`, you see manual of `dash`. [Editor's note: the bit about `dash` only applies to Debian and Debian-based distros like Ubuntu.]

### Your Answer

`~/.bash_profile` work under bash, but `~/.profile` work under Bourne and Korn shell.

Comment: Chet Ramey was the main developer for Bash.

Answer (score 6):

A login shell is simply a shell you can login as via it ssh or at the console. A non-login shell is a shell that someone can not login too. A non-login shell is often used by programs/system services.

As for your third point. It is true `.bashrc` is executed on each instance of the shell. However `.bash_profile` is only used upon login. Thus the reason for the two separate files.

`.profile` is for things that are not specifically related to Bash, like environment variables $PATH it should also be available anytime. `.bash_profile` is specifically for login shells or shells executed at login.

Comment: difference between ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile?

Comment: .profile is for things that are not specifically related to Bash, like environment variables PATH it should also be available anytime. .bash_profile is specifically for login shells or shells executed at login.

Comment: add that statement to your answer.... cos that what's my question is....

Comment: Huh?  That doesn't even answer the question?