# Trying to modify the .profile file but it is missing

Tags: bash

I am very new to the bashshell and unix. I am proficient with Java and I know a bit of C, so bash and scripting is very new to me.

I am trying to modify the .profile in my home profile to have it echo my name every time I log on - however I encountered a situation. It is missing. I have checked for the hidden files in my directory using ls - a but it isn't there.

So do I just create a .profile file? I know that there is a /etc/profile that is given to me by my administrator but I am not allowed to overwrite that file.

Also, what would I include in the .profile file if I make my own? Would it just be as simple as creating the file and adding an echo statement with it accessing my username? I have tried this, and it failed.

Here is what my current script looks like(that fails):

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/lbin:$HOME/bin:.:

export PATH
echo "My user profile has executed. Greetings!"
```

I'd like to add I'm not sure if this PATH is showing the correct path either - it is what I copied from my book.

Comment: Thanks. That helped - Off topic but do you have any resources to learn bash in general? I've looked at TLDP and I foudn it really hard to follow through. I didn't like how the book was laid out - it felt like they were throwing information all at once. I really like the format of C ansi 2nd edition by Brian and Ritchie. Concise explanations with examples and exercises.

Hope that's not inappropriate to ask in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can simply create your own copy of `.profile` in your home directory.

However, you should also make sure that the code you want to add actually belongs there and not in `.bashrc`.

Maybe read [What is the difference between .profile and .bash_profile and why don't I have a .profile file on my system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83742/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile-and-why-dont-i-have-a?rq=1)