# Execute a program at login

Tags: bash, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, profile

I'm running Arch-Linux ARM on a Raspberry Pi.

My project goal is to have a barcode scanner attached to the Pi that forwards the scanned messages to a server in a LAN.

To harden the system against power outages etc. and minimize required user interaction, I wish to set it up so that a certain user is logged in automatically at startup (done and works) and a specific program is to be run at startup (done and works but not as intended).

I've done this so far by adding

```
exec mono scannerSoftware.exe 127.0.0.1 1234 randomString
```

to `/home/certainUser/.bash_profile` so it gets executed only once even when I'm switching back and forth to root (in contrast to bashrc).

The particular problem I am having:
When I launch the system, it works as intended (login as certainUser, starting scannerSoftware.exe); BUT if I want to switch users and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, it restarts the login process, logging certainUser in again and running the program again => back to where I came from.

My guess as to why this happens is that the sys detects "login not complete, better start it again".

I could circumvent this by spamming <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> right around the login so that I practically interrupted it. Of course, this is not good practice. Suffice it to say it is not practical at all.

My question:
How can I set it up so the program gets executed AFTER login is complete so that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>'ing out brings me to a normal bash prompt as certainUser instead of beginning the endless login-cycle?

EDIT:
I'm not using any graphical interface or such, only commandline (bash on tty), because when done the system won't even have a display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answers depends on your requirements.

You might only want it to start after a particular user logs-in, alternatively you may want it to start when during reboot (a service). ?

**start on login**

When you start a program with `exec` it replaces the process that is used to start it.

- So currently, your login bash is replaced by your *scanner* and
  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> sends interrupt signal, it stops, and
  you are then logged out.
- instead of *execing* you could simply start the program, it runs in
  foreground (you don't get the prompt back).
  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> has the same effect as before, stops the
  scanner, but you will be back at the login bash prompt.
- You can start the process in the background, by appending `&` to the
  command line, this creates a new process, still displays output on
  your terminal, but you have a prompt from your login shell as well,
  so output from the background process could interfere with your
  foreground shell. You can get over this by redirecting stdout and
  stderr to a file (even /dev/null if it's not wanted), thus avoiding
  the interference.

When you logout it's still running in background, it will get a hangup signal (but can catch that), so still processing in the background. If it was attached to your terminal it will become detached (output discarded, unless you had already catered for redirection).

When you login again, then a new scanner will be started, unless you check whether there is already one running, and it's easy to do that.

**start during reboot**

The advantage with this method is you do not need to login to get the process going, the disadvantage is that it is running all the time, you may not want that.

There are 3 main system start-up mechanisms, *init*, *upstart* and *systemd*, each being different. Traditionally /etc/rc.local would be the place to add machine specific system processes.

As WilQu mentions, Arch uses *systemd*, and he has provided a recipe for this, so I won't repeat.

**advice**

Write a script to start your process, even if it's only one line, the chances are that you will want to do more than just execute it, so you might as well write the short script now. (check if it's running, store the pid, use a different random string based on date ? who knows ...).

This allows you to develop and test the script, running it by hand and ensuring it woks as desired.

Then you can add you script, where you want (by hand, login profile, system startup).

Comment: Though WilQu and fauve gave insightful and good answers too, this one did the job for me:  
I omitted the **exec** and now I get to the normal bash-promt when the program runs into issues or gets ended with ctl+C.  
Thanks!

Comment: tks for the feedback, good luck with your project.

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to launch a program at startup, a login script is the wrong place to do it.

Instead, write a systemd unit file (since Arch seems to use systemd).

Create `/etc/systemd/system/scanner.service` (or `whatever.service`)  :

```
[Unit]
Description=(description of your program)

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono /path/to/scannerSoftware.exe 127.0.0.1 1234 randomString

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And run `systemctl daemon-reload`.

Run `systemctl enable scanner.service` to make it run at startup.

You can start and stop it manually with `systemctl start scanner.service` and `systemctl stop scanner.service` and see its status with `systemctl status scanner.service`.

See [Arch Linux help about systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd)

Comment: The thing is: I need to capture the input from the barcode scanner, which works like any usb-keyboard. It reads the code and terminates with a newline, equal to me typing **barcodeContent** and hitting enter.  
therefore I need the app/service to caputre std and not run in the background.

Comment: I don't understand then. Why can't the user just launch the program when he needs it?

Comment: I think my definition of user is a bit different from the standard term here.  
The device in question together with some clones will be deployed in an industrial environment. The people who will use it have no understanding of the inner workings etc. all they want is that their scan data goes to the right magic place, no questions asked. Therefore I want the device to steer itself to the working point of the app once it gets booted, so people will switch power on, wait a minute and scan and the desired things will happen. 
There won't be any screen attached to it or anything.

Answer (score 1):

It depend from your DE but in the most cases, you have to put your command in your `~/.xinitrc` file.

`.bash_profile` is for bash (as he named). If you don’t execute bash, the content of .bash_profile will not be executed.

Comment: Actually I'm working without any graphical interface. Once the solution is in place it will not even have a display attached.
Therefore I deemed unneccesary to install the X-Server and have the pi create fancy graphics that nobody will ever see

Answer (score 0):

if you use `bash shell` you should use : `~/.bash_profile`

if you use `Tenex C shell`  or Same `TCSH` you should use : `~/.login`

if you use `C shell`   you should use : `~/.login`

if you use `Z shell`   you should use : `$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin`

if you use `Korn shell`   you should use : `~/.profile`

I answer a better answer in [Difference between ~/.profile and ~/.bash_profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45684/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile/45805#45805)

Comment: If you carefully read the OP you'll see that I'm already using ~/.bash_profile and it does not work as intended.

Comment: oh i reread, Problem doesn't relate to unix world, it's related to mono.please debutg it. or upgrade your mono.

Comment: it does work just fine when I execute it manually, plus I replaced the command with **exec echo "lol"**, had a few laughs and then the exact same problem.

Comment: At the following article you read how to disable `CTRL+C` : http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-shell-scripting-disable-controlc/