# How would I start a program when I login to terminal?

Tags: terminal

This is a simple question, but too generic to find on google, I guess.

How would I set-up a program to run every time I opened the terminal?

For example; every time I open the Terminal it runs `hello.sh` which would echo `"hello bofimpact"`.

Do I need to put `hello.sh` in a boot folder for the terminal or something?

(p.s.: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 )

Comment: Look here http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117217/execute-a-program-at-login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your command to `~/.bashrc`.