# Why does 'nohup command >& /dev/null' seem to "work" in some shells?

Tags: shell, io-redirection, nohup

I edited an [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/429977/85695) on Ask Ubuntu that was suggesting the following

```
nohup gedit >& /dev/null &
```

When they actually meant

```
nohup gedit &> /dev/null &
```

The latter correctly redirects both stderr and stdout to `/dev/null`. I was expecting the former to either create a file called `&` or, more likely, to give an error as it does for other cases:

```
$ echo "foo" >& 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Instead, it seems to work in exactly the same way as the former, a `gedit` window appears and no error message is printed.

I should also note that this is shell specific:

- `bash` (4.2.45(1)-release), `zsh` (5.0.2), `csh` (deb package version: 20110502-2) and `tcsh` (6.18.01) : works as described above, no error message, no files created.
- `dash` (0.5.7-3):

  ```
  $ nohup gedit >& /dev/null & 
  $ dash: 2: Syntax error: Bad fd number
  ```
- `ksh` (93u+ 2012-08-01): fails, but a process is apparently started (`1223`) though no `gedit` window appears:

  ```
  $ nohup gedit >& /dev/null & 
  [1] 1223
  $ ksh: /dev/null: bad file unit number
  ```
- `fish` (2.0.0):

  ```
  > nohup gedit >& /dev/null & 
  fish: Requested redirection to something that is not a file descriptor /dev/null
  nohup gedit >& /dev/null & 
                 ^
  ```

So, why does this command simply run with no errors (and no output file created) in some shells and fail in others? What is the `>&` doing in the apparently special case of `nohup`? I am guessing that `>& /dev/null` is being interpreted as `>&/dev/null` but why isn't the space causing an error in these shells?

Comment: In my machine, Ubuntu 12.04, this command run normally for `dash`.

Comment: `nohup command`,  run independent tty your application.According to my memory, `dash` extended of `ash` , `Debian ash` , `ash` developed by`OpenBSD` and it's limited shell,even maemo OS(Debian Base on n900 mobile) uses dash,`ash` family shell have limited usage expect of bash or tcsh.

Comment: @Gnouc huh, perhaps a different version (I'm on Debian)? I can't figure out how to get my `dash` to print its version out but the package is `0.5.7-3`, what's yours? Also, are you sure you're running `dash`? That's Ubuntu's default `sh` isn't it?

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh I'm not sure what your point is, I know what `nohup` does, my question is why the `>&` seems to work with nohup alone in some shells.

Comment: You can use the following link for abstarct viewing of shells: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45684/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile/45805#45805

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh again, thank you but you have completely missed the point of my question.

Comment: @terdon: mine is 0.5.7-2. I use `bash` as default shell. But I haved switched to `dash` before running this command.

Comment: When I do that in bash and then do jobs, I see this as command (note >& changed to &>) `$ jobs
[1]+  Running nohup gedit &>/dev/null &
`

Comment: @XTian umm, the whole point is the `>&`, `&>` is just shorthand for `2>&1 >` so of course it works. I think that the shells where this works are simply ignoring the space between the `>&` and `/dev/null`, `>&` means redirect to the _file descriptor_ that follows, `>&2` means redirect to stderr for example.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
nohup gedit &> /dev/null
```

is POSIX syntax and is the same as:

```
nohup gedit &
> /dev/null
```

That is run `nohup gedit` in background and then do a `> /dev/null` redirection without running a command.

```
nohup gedit >& /dev/null
```

is not POSIX syntax and is the `csh` way to redirect both stdout and stderr to /dev/null. `csh` doesn't have the `2>&1` operator as found in Bourne, so it's the only way `csh` has to redirect stderr.

`zsh` (as often) also provides with the `csh` syntax, but it also supports the `x>&y` *fd duplication* operator of the Bourne shell, which means there's a conflict there.

```
ls >&file
```

redirects `ls`'s stdout and stderr to `file`, but if the file is `2`, you've got a problem as

```
ls >&2
```

means redirect stdout to the resource pointed to by fd 2 (`dup(2, 1)`). So you need to write it:

```
ls >& ./2
```

if you wanted to redirect both the stdout and stderr of `ls` into a file called `2` in the current directory; or use the standard syntax.

`bash` initially did no understand `>&`, but it introduced the `&>` operator instead for that, breaking POSIX compliance in the process (though it's unlikely a script would use `cmd &> xxx`).

`ksh` copied that operator in ksh93t+ in 2009, mksh in R35 in 2008 (disabled in `posix` mode) but not `>&`.

`bash` added support for `>&` in 2.05.

busybox `sh` added support for both `&>` and `>&` in 1.13 (2008).

Neither `>&` nor `&>` as meaning redirect stdout and stderr are POSIX/Bourne.

If you want to redirect both stdout and stderr portably, the syntax is

```
cmd > file 2>&1
```

Comment: Do you mean Bash in `POSIX/Bourne` by "Bourne"?