# Loading .profile from .bash_profile or not using bash_profile at all?

Tags: environment-variables

I am on a MAC running Yosemite.

Until recently, I only had a .profile, in which I added directories to my PATH.

Now I have a .bash_profile, which from what I experienced and later read online, causes the .profile to be ignored when opening a terminal window.

After some readings, I do understand how .pofile and .bash_profile differ.  I do get that .bash_profile is only invoked when starting a shell.

I am however still not sure, for a basic user, what the drawbacks are, if any, in either:

- calling .profile from .bash_profile,
- or simply ignoring .bash_profile
  and setting all environment variables I may need from a shell in the
  .profile file directly.

For example, I read [here](http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others) that since .profile is ignored when .bash_profile is present, I could just add

```
. ~/.profile
```

in my bash_profile to invoke .profile.

And alternatively, though I understand that .bash_profile would allow me to set variables not needed outside of bash, I still *can* set everything I need in .profile and do not see what using .bash_profile brings me.

Comment: I read about this post (and others). My question is about recommended usage here.

Comment: See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45684/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-and-bash-profile The answer as to what is recommended is pretty much "what works for you"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Traditional sh reads the file `~/.profile` at startup when it's a [login shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell).

Bash, which is backwards compatible with sh but offers additional features, reads `.bash_profile`, and if that doesn't exist, tries `.profile` instead¹. This allows you to have a `.profile` for plain sh and a `.bash_profile` taking advantage of bash's extra features when your login shell is bash.

Bash also reads another file, `.bashrc`, when it's invoked interactively. That's the place to put prompts, aliases, completion setup, etc. However, it doesn't read that file in an interactive login shell. So your `.bash_profile` should source `.bashrc` when the shell is running interactively — otherwise you'd have to maintain separate files.

There's rarely any reason to depart from the following content for `.bash_profile`:

```
. ~/.profile
case $- in *i*) . ~/.bashrc;; esac
```

Put login-time things like environment variable definitions in `.profile` and things for interactive shells in `.bashrc`.

If you only ever use bash as your login shell, you might instead not have a `.profile`, and put login-time stuff directly in `.bash_profile`, plus the line to load `.bashrc` when interactive.

¹  <sub>It also tries `.bash_login` before `.profile` but that's not really useful.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for actually answering my question regarding recommended usage!