# How can I get colors to show up in terminal (macOS Sierra)

Tags: bash, terminal, osx

I added `export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx` to my `.bash_profile`, saved the file, then in terminal ran `source .bash_profile` and was able to see colors. However, upon closing the terminal and opening again, I saw that there were no colors even when the my `.bash_profile` is still the same.

EDIT: Using `Terminal.app` and `bash`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some terminals don't run a new login shell each time you open them so they are sourcing your `.bashrc` file instead of `.bash_profile`  I would recommend putting your colors in the `.bashrc` file.  Another solution that I probably wouldn't recommend but a lot of people do is to source your `.bash_profile` from within `.bashrc`

More info:  http://www.joshstaiger.org/archives/2005/07/bash_profile_vs.html

Comment: Thanks, but curious, why would you not recommend sourcing `.bash_profile` from within `.bashrc`? Also, according to that documentation, every new terminal window sources `.bash_profile` so shouldn't my situation be working?

Comment: It just depends on what you put in your `.bash_profile` I guess.  It's intended for trivial (probably not the right word) user preference/functionality modifications and could cause problems if it's sourced every time bash is called.  For example you may want to create the following alias `alias du="du -kh"` which if put into the .bashrc file could cause some scripts to malfunction.

Comment: The documentation says that "if you’ve already logged into your machine and open a new terminal window (xterm) inside Gnome or KDE, then .bashrc is executed before the window command prompt"  The exception is mac's terminalx app which should source your `.bash_profile` but I'm guessing you are using something else.

Comment: @ron Because you should do the opposite: source `.bashrc` from `.bash_profile`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192521/loading-profile-from-bash-profile-or-not-using-bash-profile-at-all/192550#192550

Comment: @Gilles I've added `source ~/.bashrc` to my `bash_profile` but still no changes (exited `Terminal` and re-opened). I also tried `if [ -s ~/.bashrc ]; then source ~/.bashrc; fi` to no luck.

Comment: @ron Please edit your question to indicate which terminal emulator and which shell you're using. Apparently you aren't using the default configuration. Is your `~/.bash_profile` read at all? It is in the default configuration on macOS; most other configurations read `~/.bashrc` when opening a terminal. Add `set -x` at the top of the file to make it print a trace of all the commands it runs, check that this appears on your terminal.

Comment: @Gilles Ok, I use Terminal.app and Bash, how would I tell if `~/.bash_profile` is read?

Comment: Add the following line to the bottom of your `.bash_profile`:  `echo "HEY! My bash profile is being read!"` .   You should see something like this at login:  `Last login: Mon Aug  7 10:50:50 on ttys000
You have mail.
HEY! My bash profile is being read!
joyentmac2252:~ jessebutryn$`

Comment: @Jesse_b @Gilles Ok I see it says at login: `'[' -s /Users/jeremy/.bashrc ']'
+ source /Users/jeremy/.bashrc
++ export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx
++ LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx`

Answer (score 3):

You need to set two environment variables in your `~/.bashrc` file.

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=gxBxhxDxfxhxhxhxhxcxcx
```