# I have multiple copies of .bash_profile, which one is actually being used? (if any)

Tags: shell, bashrc

I think at some point I messed up my `.bash_profile` and I have multiple now. I am trying to customize my shell but I am not sure which `.bash_profile` to use, if any. I thought `.bashrc` file was more often used?

I am running OSX - El Capitan

```
ls -la | more
total 480


-rw-------    1 Matthew  staff   6404 Feb 16 23:57 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--    1 Matthew  staff    719 Jan 19 20:18 .bash_profile
-rw-r--r--    1 Matthew  staff    335 Oct  7 12:35 .bash_profile.macports-saved_2017-01-19_at_20:18:05
-rw-r--r--    1 Matthew  staff    167 Jul 16  2015 .bash_profile.pysave
drwxr-xr-x  208 Matthew  staff   7072 Feb 18 19:41 .bash_sessions
```

Answer (score 35):

No, you only have one and it's called `.bash_profile`.  Bash will not read the ones with additional suffixes.

The other `.bash_profile.*` files looks like backups, possibly made by  different software installations (from last year and the year before). Run a `diff -u` between your `.bash_profile` and the others (in turn) to see what's different about them if you wish, e.g.

```
$ diff -u .bash_profile .bash_profile.pysave
```

`.bashrc` is used by interactive shells and `.bash_profile` is used for login shells.  If you're adding aliases, add them to `.bashrc`.

See also "[What is the difference between ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.gnomerc, /etc/bash_bashrc, /etc/screenrc ...?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40708/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-bashrc-bash-profile-gnomer)"