# Ubuntu messed up PATH

Tags: ubuntu, path

on trying to configurate go programming language i messed up my PATH in linux. I can not do any commands without specifing the path:

```
frede@frede-Lenovo-V110-15ISK:~$ ls
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
ls: command not found
frede@frede-Lenovo-V110-15ISK:~$ echo $PATH
/home/frede/bin:/home/frede/.local/bin:PATH:/home/frede/go/bin
```

However I can run it with the specified path. I tried to solve this problem at looking at similar threads, but I just couldn't find the solution for me. Can you please help me?

**UPDATE**

```
frede@frede-Lenovo-V110-15ISK:~$ grep 'PATH=' ~/.profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile /etc/profile
/home/frede/.profile:PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
/home/frede/.bashrc:export GOPATH=/home/frede/go
/home/frede/.bashrc:export PATH=PATH:/home/frede/go/bin
grep: /home/frede/.bash_profile: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) replace the output you show with the output of `LC_ALL=C ls`, that will give you English error messages; ii) show us the output of `grep 'PATH=' ~/.profile ~/.bashrc ~/.bash_profile /etc/profile`.

Comment: Looks like a typo of PATH=PATH... instead of PATH=$PATH...

Comment: You need to correct this line `export PATH=PATH:/home/frede/go/bin` in your `/home/frede/.bashrc` file into `export PATH="$PATH":/home/frede/go/bin`.

Comment: This is a protected file. I tried to vi/vim once and completely messed up a file, so will this do it as well? echo "export PATH=$PATH:/home/frede/go/bin >> ~./bashrc" ?

Comment: No, that particular line has to be fixed. You can echo, but that line needs to be removed then.

Comment: Open it with a normal editor. vi/m is difficult (easy to break things).

Comment: And your echo command is not correct, so better just use a simple editor.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I first tried to edit the /etc/.barshrc which is private. But its the /home/Frede/.bashrc , just as you said it. Works now all for me. Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Restore

There should be a right PATH in your `/etc/profile`. I don't know how you messed up your PATH, but sourcing `/etc/profile` should bring things back to normal. As long as you didn't edit that one. So try this:

```
. /etc/profile
```

#### Proper PATH setup

Assuming you're using bash, you might make use of `.bashrc` file (instead of `.profile`) to setup your path. You can use a similar entry to the one you might find within `/etc/profile`:

```
# set PATH so it includes your private Go bin folder if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/go/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

If you aren't using bash, adjust the PATH (same way as above) in your private `.profile` file instead of `.bashrc`.

Finally, source the file you've modified:

```
. ~/.bashrc   # or
. ~/.profile
```

(note: `.profile` usually sources `.bashrc` -- see references for further info)

And if you've polluted some of your files with an erroneous PATH definition, you need to clean that up. Follow Terdon's comment under your question for this.

#### References

- https://serverfault.com/questions/261802/what-are-the-functional-differences-between-profile-bash-profile-and-bashrc
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment
- https://superuser.com/questions/789448/choosing-between-bashrc-profile-bash-profile-etc
- [What is the difference between ~/.profile, ~/.bashrc, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.gnomerc, /etc/bash_bashrc, /etc/screenrc ...?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40708/what-is-the-difference-between-profile-bashrc-bash-profile-gnomer)